# Can I change a require()'d module's cwd without using process.chdir()

Tags: node.js, module, npm, chdir

I have a NodeJS module that does a lot of work on the filesystem in a particular directory. I would like all filesystem operations inside the module to be done relative to that directory - (let's call it `/home/me/data`).

I realise I could change the current working directory with `process.chdir("/home/me/data");` but that would mess up the working directory of any other modules that are using my module.

Is there a way that a child module can have a different working directory than it's parent?
I don't want to have to pass a variable through to *every* sub-module to be appended to the filepath of `fs.readFile(filepath);` calls.

Are there any elegant ways of achieving this?

P.s. child process spawning / forking is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

No. The cwd is one-per-process in unix. In general, code that explicitly references `cwd` in *usually* misguided. It only makes sense for certain utilities like `git`, and even then the OS handles relative to absolute conversion for you. Have you considered expanding your paths with `path.resolve` so they are absolute before passing them to the module in question?

Comment: At the moment I am passing a resolved path to the module. The issue is that the module has to pass that path to each of it's sub-modules and their sub-modules etc... Just seems a little bit messy

Comment: Hey @Peter, can you expand your answer on why referencing `cwd` from a submodule is usually misguided? `path.resolve` will eventually use `cwd` for example.

Comment: I'll make you a deal. you add concrete details to your question to replace the vague/abstract stuff and I'll expand my answer. what Durr's your program do and why? how is cwd relevant at all?

Answer (score 0):

The 'relative-fs' module on NPM is one solution https://www.npmjs.com/package/relative-fs - It wraps the fs library to make it's methods relative to a given directory.

**disclaimer:** I haven't actually used it yet.